# file_put_contents wipes the file

Tags: php, file-io

If two people load the same page within approximately 5 milliseconds of each other, the two simultaneous `file_put_contents` calls seem to wipe the file blank, losing all data.

How can I write to files securely in such a manner that the file will never be wiped blank, no matter how many people load the page at the exact same time?

I cannot use a mysql database for this, that'd be extremely excessive.

Comment: Why would using a database to handle such concurrency be excessive?

Comment: @Brad Because it's one single file holding a small amount of data.

Comment: will have to guess what your code has here. Are you using File append? and are you using flock() to lock the file if it has been accessed?

Comment: @Duniyadnd Read the question title, body, and tags more closely.

Comment: Use a unique filename instead of a fixed one?

Comment: @Cyclone - I did - which was why I asked you those questions. It seems that "mrkmg" mentioned flock() and you don't know anything about it which indicates why you responded the way you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) has third parameter. Write `LOCK_EX` there.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this flag, thanks for sharing the info. I've implemented it already as a safe-guard in some libraries I've written.

Comment: Is the `LOCK_EX` flag blocking? It should be, otherwise...kinda pointless

Comment: @Wesley Murch, glad to useful )

Comment: @Cyclone, did you read manual? `Acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing.`

Answer (score 1):

In your php use a while loop and check for a file lock.

Here is some reading
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

EDIT

```
$fp = fopen("/tmp/lock.txt", "r+");
while(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX))
      {
      usleep(10);
      }
//do stuff
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: So until it receives the lock, it won't be able to write to the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Writes a file without the worry on simultaneous file writings.
 *
 * @param mixed $data - Data to put into the file.
 * @param string $filePath - Path to the file to put data into.
 * @param number $timeOut - The maximum time (milliseconds) until method attempts to write file (defaults to 1000).
 * @return bool - Returns true if data has been written.
 */
function writeDataToFileSafely($data, $filePath, $timeOut = 1000)
{
    $interval = 10; // milliseconds
    $elapsed = 0;
    $success = false;

    while($success === false && $elapsed < $timeout)
    {
        $success = file_put_contents($filePath, $data, LOCK_EX);
        usleep(interval * 1000); // to microseconds
        $elapsed += $interval;
    }

    return $success;
}
```